# Flask how to calculate tags count

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask

I developing simple blog with tagging support. Actually I would like to add tags cloud functionality and I need to get count of each tag used in blog.
My Blog and Tag models looks like:

```
class Blog(db.Model, ObservableModel):
    __tablename__ = "blogs"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('blog_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=True)

    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=tags_to_blogs_association_table)

class Post(db.Model, ObservableModel):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    ......................

    blog = relationship('Blog', backref = db.backref('blogs', lazy='dynamic'))
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=tags_to_posts_association_table)

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('post_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True)
```

I want to collect dictionary of pairs like `tag_name : count` and only one way is to iterate over `Blog.tags` collection with retrieving posts which contains tag item.
Actually I am not sure that it is the best (from performance point of view) solution, maybe flask-sqlalchemy provides join function?
Question: how to implement in Python using Flask-SQLAlchemy query like following:

```
select
    t.id,
    t.title,
    count(post_id)
from tags t
join tags_to_blogs b on t.id=b.tag_id
join tags_to_posts p on t.id=p.tag_id
group by (t.id)
having b.blog_id=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = db.session.query(Tag, db.count(Post.id))
query = query.filter(
    (tags_to_posts_association_table.tag_id == Tag.id) & \
    (tags_to_posts_association_table.post_id == Post.id)
)
query = query.group_by(Tag.id)
```

This generates this query:

```
SELECT tags.id AS tags_id, tags.title AS tags_title, count(posts.id) AS count_1 
FROM tags, posts, tags_to_posts 
WHERE tags_to_posts.tag_id = tags.id AND tags_to_posts.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY tags.id
```

A cleaner way could be something like this:

```
query = db.session.query(Tag, db.func.count(Post.id))
# This works but the preferred way is what's below it
#query = query.join(tags_to_posts_association_table, Post)
query = query.join(Post.tags)
query = query.group_by(Tag.id)
```

This generates this query:

```
SELECT tags.id AS tags_id, tags.title AS tags_title, count(posts.id) AS count_1 
FROM tags INNER JOIN tags_to_posts ON tags.id = tags_to_posts.tag_id INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = tags_to_posts.post_id GROUP BY tags.id
```

All these produce the same result, and you can chain them just like this:

```
query = db.session.query(Tag.title, db.func.count(Post.id)).join(Post.tags).group_by(Tag.id)

# This will give you a dictionary with keys the tag titles, and values the count of each
# Because you can iterate over the query, which will give you the results
# Or you can use query.all() and use it as you prefer.
results = dict(query)
```

Also, I'm not sure if it's `db.func.count` or `db.count`. In any way you can always `from sqlalchemy import func` and use `func.count`.

Comment: `query.join(Post.tags)` should work. I'd also recommend against first way (implicit joining), explicit joins indeed look cleaner.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas That's what I thought too, and `query.join(Post)` is supposed to work IIRC, but it just raised an exception saying it can't find foreign keys linking `posts` to `tags`. My guess is there was something wrong with the relationships, or maybe only `query.join(Post.tags)` works. I'll try it out to see what exactly was wrong...

Comment: I think `query.join(Post)` doesn't work because this is a many-to-many relationship with association table involved.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way (pseudo code, can't remember the proper alchemy syntax but you should be able to 'convert' it quiet easily)

```
tags = Tags.findAll()
for tag in tags:
    myDict[tag] = Post.find(tags=tag).count()
```

And at the and you should have all tags in myDict with their count

Comment: Thanks, I already checked it. It is quite obvious, but not too effective - for each tag I got 1 additional query.